# How can I redirect Visual Studio’s “Output” window to DebugView?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

I’m using Visual Studio 2010 to write unmanaged C++ code.

When debugging, anything printed using `OutputDebugString` or MFC’s `TRACE` macro goes to Visual Studio’s “Output” window.

I would prefer to see the output in DebugView instead, while still running under the MSVC debugger. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible.  Whatever debugger the app runs in gets first dibs on any such messages.  DebugView can only intercept the messages when the app is not running inside of any debugger.

Answer (score 1):

likely not possible, by design.. if you open two DebugView instances, there's also only one receiving the messages.